# Foreach loop does not add counter

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-5.8

I have this custom *foreach* loop at Blade:

```
<div id="dynamic_field">
    @foreach($niloufars as $niloufar)
        @php 
            $counter = 1;
        @endphp 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="text-danger force-required"></span>
                    <label for="niloufar_name">Title</label>
                    <input type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        name="niloufar_name_{{ $counter }}" value="{{ $niloufar->name }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="text-danger force-required"></span>
                    <label for="niloufar_link">Link</label>
                    <input type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        name="niloufar_link_{{ $counter }}" value="{{ $niloufar->link }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        @php
            $counter = $counter + 1;
        @endphp
    @endforeach
</div>
```

So as you can see I have set a `$counter` variable set to **1** at the 1st iteration and then I add **1** to it so that for the next iteration it will be **2**.

Therefore I can set unique names for form fields in order for further process.

But the problem with this is that, the variable is just set to **1** the whole time:

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="text-danger force-required"></span>
                <label for="niloufar_name">Title</label>
                <input type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="niloufar_name_1" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="text-danger force-required"></span>
                <label for="niloufar_link">Link</label>
                <input type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="niloufar_link_1" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
                         
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="text-danger force-required"></span>
                <label for="niloufar_name">Title</label>
                <input type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="niloufar_name_1" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="text-danger force-required"></span>
                <label for="niloufar_link">Link</label>
                <input type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="niloufar_link_1" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So what's going wrong here? How can I show current iteration properly for each form field name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the setting of the counter before the foreach (as it is, you are setting it to 1 in the beginning of every loop):

```
@php 
    $counter = 1;
@endphp 
@foreach($niloufars as $niloufar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies in your counter Decleration you should assign your counter outside of `@foreach` then increment counter. but now in your code you are doing increment and again making it **$count = 1**.
Hope you will understand this logical mistake.